# How to show tooltip description in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, ide, androidstudio-settings

The key in my Eclipse(ADT linux):

```
'Name': 'Show Tooltip Description'
'Description': 'Displays information for the current caret location in a focused hover'
'Binding' : 'F2'
```

Any similar key in Android Studio?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd> to show the quick javadoc of current caret location.

If you want it on hover go to

```
File > Settings > Editor
```

and tick the checkbox "Show quick doc on mouse move". You can also set the time delay after hover to make sure just moving cursor in editor doesn't show the javadocs.

**EDIT :**

As per comments

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> can be used for Quick Fixes in Android Studio, It will give you drop down for possible fixes same like in Eclipse.

Answer (score 12):

The strange thing about Android Studio and tool tips is that Android doesn't call them tool tips. Instead "quick documentation on mouse move." Oh my.

Anyways, for Android Studio 2.1.2 IDE installed on Mac OS X, enable tool tips by:
-"Android Studio" menu
-"Preferences..." menu item
-open "Editor" twirl
-Click on the "General" twirl, not to be confused with twirling open the "General" twirl (this kind of stuff is bad UX design).
-"Other" section
-third field down in the section which is a checkbox labeled "Show quick documentation on mouse move."

Oh BTW, this setting is disabled by default which is very strange.

Answer (score 7):

For **Android Studio 3.6.3** IDE installed on macOS, enable tool tips by:

```
Preferences > Editor > General > Code Completion > Show the documentation popup in 0 ms
```